# How do I attach a managed IAM policy and an inline/custom IAM policy to IAM roles?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to attach a managed IAM Policy ARN (like `AmazomS3FullAccess`) and an inline/custom IAM policy (written in JSON in terraform file) to a single IAM Role.

by using `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` I am able to attach only one policy, what's the way to attach both?

```
variables.tf
------------

variable "iam_policy_arn" {
  description = "IAM Policy to be attached to role"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaFullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMFullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"]
}




main.tf
-------


resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<-EOF
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{
        "Service":"ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{
        "Service":"sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS":"*"
      },
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}    
  EOF
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role_policy_attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"
  count      = "${length(var.iam_policy_arn)}"
  policy_arn = "${element(var.iam_policy_arn,count.index)}"

}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "test_profile" {
  name = "test_profile"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"
}
```

now I want to attach a custom policy like below to the role

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "test_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.test_role.id

  policy = <<-EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [
          "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

How do I attach a managed IAM policy and a custom IAM policy to IAM roles?

Comment: I want to attach `test_policy` to `test_role` by using `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`

Comment: You could have a seperate template file for your policy and then add both the actions from there into the file. Have a look at this https://medium.com/@mitesh_shamra/terraform-managing-policy-using-templates-e254b2d17907

Comment: I wanna attach both managed IAM policy and custom IAM policy in JSON(as a file or in terraform) to a single role `test_role`, in the above code I have already attached managed AWS policies to `test_role`,  I want to attach `test_policy` to test role as well. The link you mentioned shows how to add a custom policy to a role. Im looking for both custom policy and AWS managed policy to single role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to attach a managed IAM policy and an inline/custom IAM policy to IAM role using the below code.

```
# variables.tf
variable "cloudwatch_lambda_iam_policy_arn" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "IAM Policy to be attached to AWS CloudWatch Lambda role"
  default     = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCloudDirectoryFullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"]
}

#------------------------------------------------------------

# lambda.tf
resource "aws_iam_role" "awsmetrics_exec_role" {
  name = "awsmetrics-exec-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# custom/inline policy
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "sts_assumerole_lambda" {
  name = "sts-assumerole-lambda"
  role = aws_iam_role.awsmetrics_exec_role.id

  policy = <<-EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeRole",
        "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage",
        "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
        "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

# AWS managed policies
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "awsmetrics_role_policy_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.awsmetrics_exec_role.name
  count      = length(var.cloudwatch_lambda_iam_policy_arn)
  policy_arn = element(var.cloudwatch_lambda_iam_policy_arn, count.index)
}
```

Comment: What is the difference to your code from your question? I couldn't find the solution in your code. Could you elaboeate your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to modify the policy to your needs but that's what it would look like. You can do the following:

```
data "template_file" "test_role_template" {
 template = "${file("pathToRoleJson")}"
}

data "template_file" "test_policy_template" {
    template = "${file("pathToPolicyJson")}"
    vars = {
      customParam    = "${var.ValueOfParam}"
    }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
    name     = "roleName"
    assume_role_policy = "${data.template_file.test_role.rendered}"
}

#-----------------------------------------
resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_role_policy" {
  name   = "policyName"
  policy = "${data.template_file.test_policy_template.rendered}"
}

# Attach policy to role nat_ec2_role
#-----------------------------------------
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "nat_ec2_role_policy-attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.test_role_policy.arn}"
}



# Policy Template File
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{
        "Service":"ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{
        "Service":"sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS":"*"
      },
       {
        "Action": [
          "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}    


resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "test_profile" {
  name = "test_profile"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't add the AWS managed policy to the role. Your solution only adds the custom policy. That is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them as variable or declare them as a local value, and then iterate over such variable.

For example:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach" {
  count      = length(var.policies)
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_role.name
  policy_arn = ${var.policies[count.index]}
}
```

where `var.policies` is a list of policies `["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::<your_account>:policy/your_policy"]`

Comment: I want to add custom policy through JSON in terraform itself, for example `resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "test_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.test_role.id

  policy = <<-EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [
          "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the inline policy with embedded JSON as follows:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "test_policy" {
  name = "test_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.test_role.id

  policy = <<-EOF
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": [
          "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
  }
  EOF
}
```

Or you can use a **`aws_iam_policy_document`** to get better error-checking in IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "policy" {
  name        = "test-policy"
  description = "A test policy"

  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_ec2_describe
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_ec2_describe" {
  version = "2012-10-17"

  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:Describe*",
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Side note: you can more cleanly attach the Amazon Managed Policies using an **`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`** resource with **`for_each`** like this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "managed_policy_attachments" {
  for_each   = {for arn in var.iam_policy_arns : arn => arn}
  role       = aws_iam_role.test_role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.managed_policies[each.key]
}
```

Side note: you can also use **`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`** for cleaner **`assume_role_policy`** setup:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
  name = "test_role"

  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_ec2_and_sagemaker
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_ec2_and_sagemaker" {
  version = "2012-10-17"

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowEC2AndSageMaker"
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole",
    ]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "sagemaker.amazonaws.com",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Background

AWS offers different identity-based policies, see [Identity-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based):

> - **Managed policies** – Standalone identity-based policies that you can attach to multiple users, groups, and roles in your AWS account. There are two types of managed policies:
>
>   - **AWS managed policies** – Managed policies that are created and managed by AWS.
>   - **Customer managed policies** – Managed policies that you create and manage in your AWS account. Customer managed policies provide more precise control over your policies than AWS managed policies.
> - **Inline policies** – Policies that you add directly to a single user, group, or role. Inline policies maintain a strict one-to-one relationship between a policy and an identity. They are deleted when you delete the identity.

You can mix these policies, see [Choosing between managed policies and inline policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies-choosing-managed-or-inline.html):

> You can use both managed and inline policies together to define common and unique permissions for a principal entity.

Terraform can add a policy to a role with:

- [`aws_iam_role_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy) (for inline policy)
- [`inline_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#inline_policy) (for inline policy)
- [`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/rgeraskin/aws3/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment) (for AWS/custom managed policy)
- [`aws_iam_policy_attachment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy_attachment) (for AWS/custom managed policy)
- [`managed_policy_arns`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#managed_policy_arns) (for AWS/custom managed policy)

But you can't mix them arbitrarily, see [`aws_iam_role_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy):

> For a given role, this resource is incompatible with using the `aws_iam_role` resource `inline_policy` argument. When using that argument and this resource, both will attempt to manage the role's inline policies and Terraform will show a permanent difference.

and [`aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/rgeraskin/aws3/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment):

> The usage of this resource conflicts with the `aws_iam_policy_attachment` resource and will permanently show a difference if both are defined.

and [`aws_iam_role`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role):

> If you use this resource's `managed_policy_arns` argument or `inline_policy` configuration blocks, this resource will take over exclusive management of the role's respective policy types (e.g., both policy types if both arguments are used). These arguments are incompatible with other ways of managing a role's policies, such as `aws_iam_policy_attachment`, `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`, and `aws_iam_role_policy`. If you attempt to manage a role's policies by multiple means, you will get resource cycling and/or errors.

### Solution

You can use `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` and `aws_iam_role_policy` together.

**Example**

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_role" {
  name               = "my-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.instance-assume-role-policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "rekognition" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.rekognition.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "s3" {
  name = "my-inline-policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.my_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:ListBucket",
        ]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = [
          "my-bucket",
          "my-bucket/*",
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

### Additional information

If you want to validate your custom managed / inline policy by Terraform, you could use [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document), see [Refactor your policy](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/aws/aws-iam-policy#refactor-your-policy):

> The `aws_iam_policy_document` data source uses HCL to generate a JSON representation of an IAM policy document. Writing the policy as a Terraform configuration has several advantages over defining your policy inline in the `aws_iam_policy` resource.
>
> - Terraform data sources makes applying policies to your AWS resources more flexible. You can overwrite, append, or update policies with this resource by using the `source_policy_documents` and `override_policy_documents` arguments.
> - Terraform data sources make it easier to reuse policies throughout your environment.
> - Terraform error checking automatically formats your policy document into correct JSON when you run your apply.